# How does std::shared_ptr converts across class hierarchy when passing by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

Looking at ***20.8.2.2 Class template shared_ptr*** [util.smartptr.shared] I realized that `std::shared_ptr` has template copy constructors and assignment operators that allow the conversion from `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>` if and only if `Derived*` is convertible to `Base*`. These conversion are done (in my understanding) only via the templated copy constructors and assignment operators. However, it seems I can also pass a `shared_ptr<Derived>` to a function that takes `shared_ptr<Base>&` (i.e., pass by reference). It seems that there should be an implicit conversion operator, but according to the standard there is none.

The code below clarifies what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {};
struct Derived: Base {};

void f(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& ) {}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> spDerived(new Derived);

    // conversion below is OK, via template copy ctor
    std::shared_ptr<Base> spBase(spDerived); 
    // also OK, via template copy assignment operator
    spBase = spDerived; 

    // why is this OK? Cannot see any conversion operators in
    // 20.8.2.2 Class template shared_ptr [util.smartptr.shared]
    f(spDerived); 
}
```

**My question:** In this case, who's performing the conversion from `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>` in the call `f(spDerived)`? (for the compiler `shared_ptr<Derived>` has no relation whatsoever with `shared_ptr<Base>`, even if `Derived` is a child of `Base`)

Comment: A temporary `std::shared_ptr<Base>` is created via the converting constructor, and bound to the reference. In other words, the call is equivalent to `f(std::shared_ptr<Base>(spDerived))`

Comment: I said converting constructor, not copy constructor (constructor templates are never copy constructors; /end pedantic mode). In any case, how can you know that no constructor is being called? Since your function is a no-op, most likely the whole call is being optimized away.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think I understand what's going on, the compiler can perform one user-defined conversion, and can invoke the template conversion ctor... the temp is then bound to the const ref.

Comment: Both your question and the accepted answer below talk of template copy constructors. As Igor has already explained, there are no such things. Constructors templates can never be copy/move constructors. The constructor being used here is the second one numbered (9) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). You've already understood what's going on here, but it might be interesting to remove the `const` in `f`'s parameter type and see how the code fails to compile (won't fail on MSVC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A temporary is created via the template copy ctor and that copy is what is referenced. The ctor is implicit so it may be legally called in this situation. Fundamentally there is no difference here between this call and say, `f(std::string); f("hello");`. The exact same mechanisms are at play. It's a regular implicit conversion.

Comment: I pass by const reference though, so it should be safe. I just don't understand why the copy constructor is invoked.

Comment: @vsoftco: Oh, I must have completely brainfarted and did not see the `const` at all. The copy constructor is invoked because it's implicit, so the compiler can implicitly create a temporary.